# Test framework for multi-layered application html5/sql/c++

Tags: c++, sql, html, unit-testing, testing

I am an experienced c++ developer, but I have not spend much work in design of applications. Question:

I am working on an existing application that consists of the following layers

- HTML5 front-end
- Database that communicates with the front-end via stored procedures
- Back-end c++ application running on Linux servers that communicate with the database via a job-daemon

We want to introduce more automatic testing into the application. We want full end-to-end tests, as well as individual tests on each level, i.e. test of front-end, test of SQL stored procedures, and test of back-end.

Is there some kind of unifying framework where I can setup tests across all layers? And e.g. a board that provides overview of test results.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the backend you can use any tools that allow you to create http call . Phpunit, junit, curl + scripting . For the frontend you can use mocha, expect, jasmine..  but at this day i don’t know an unifying framework containing tests for each layer.

Comment: What about stored procedures on a sql databse?

Comment: I suggest you look at other languages (such as C#/ASP.NET/Angular/DotNet core) that have much better support for what you are trying to do.  As a quick example, from Visual Studio 2017, you could do File/New Solution and have a complete Angular (HTML5) SPA, with middleware APIs (conforming to REST/JSON all the buzzwords), and a backend that supports any SQL database you care to imagine, created for you.